# AWS EC2 get notified when a tag changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to call a lambda function when my EC2 tag "Something" changes. Is it possible? If I cannot listen to changes to a specific tag, I could listen on EC2 config changes. How can I do that? I am not sure which option to select on cloudwatch events ...

**UPDATE**

I tried AWS Config, but it appears that it only monitors config changes when instance is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Amazon CloudWatch Events with AWS CloudTrail to call a Lambda function, triggered off a `CreateTags` event. (Changing a tag is actually treated as creating a tag.)

- Turn on AWS CloudTrail for your region (this involves pointing it to an Amazon S3 bucket for log storage)
- Create an **Amazon SNS topic**
- Create an **AWS Lambda function** with a trigger on the SNS topic
- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule**:

  - **Service Name:** EC2
  - **Event Type:** AWS API Call via CloudTrail
  - **Specific Operations:** CreateTags
  - **Add Target:** Select your Lambda function

Your Lambda function will receive a notification when a tag is created/changed.

Comment: Note, CloudTrail can be quite slow when it comes to noting API calls. Don't be surprised if it takes 10+ minutes after the actual action takes place, before cloudwatch rule is actually triggered.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has said "[EventBridge is the evolution of Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cwe-now-eb.html)". To build on John's accepted solution, the following uses Amazon EventBridge and doesn't need AWS CloudTrail or AWS Lambda. Through my tests it reports tag changes within seconds of it changing.

- Create an EventBridge Rule with an event pattern
- Add a custom pattern under "Customer pattern (JSON editor)" and paste
  the following JSON object, which will match any tag changes for EC2
  instances. This can be narrowed down to specific instances, accounts, regions and more, you can learn about event pattern filtering in [the
  documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html).

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.tag"],
  "detail-type": ["Tag Change on Resource"],
  "resources": [{
    "prefix": "arn:aws:ec2"
  }]
}
```

- For the rule target you can publish directly to SNS, CloudWatch Logs and other services from the drop down.

To learn more about creating rules you can refer to [this page in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule.html).